# IOS NSJSONSerialization deserialize NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json

I'm try to deserialize an array a json string.
the json is like this

```
{
   "id": "2559",
    "tags": [
        "Tag1",
        "Tag2"
    ]
}
```

My code is

```
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData  options:kNilOptions error:nil];
myEntity= [[MyEntity alloc] init];

myEntity.id          = [json objectForKey:@"id"];
myEntity.tags        = [json objectForKey:@"tags"];
```

And MyEntity is

```
@interface MyEntity: NSObject{
    NSString *id;
    NSArray *tags;
...
```

My problem is that I can't view the value of tags,  myEntity.tags is an array with 2 item **empty**.

How can i deserilize tags?

EDIT
Sorry to everybody, I was wrong.
It work fine, if I log the tags with

```
NSLog(@"%@", [json objectForKey:@"tags"]);
NSLog(@"%@", myEntity.tags);
```

I can see the same log

```
(
    tags1,
    tags2
)
```

I was confused beacuse in the area near the logs i saw this

```
tags = (NSArray *) 0x07... @"2 objects"
    [0]
    [1]
```

thanx to everybody and sorry again for my mistake

Comment: Are you sure the JSON parser has returned an `NSDictionary` object? Try: `if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]) { myEntity = ... etc } else { NSLog(@"JSON Parse failure"); }`.

Comment: What is your output if you do `NSLog(@"%@", json);` Can you put this into the question?

Comment: `id` is an Objective-C keyword so calling a property that is not a good idea.

Comment: @Paul.s Good spot; I would have thought the compiler would have something to say about that?

Comment: What do you mean by "myEntity.tags is an array with 2 item empty"?  What do you get when you NSLog myEntity.tags?

Comment: @Paul.s yes, i didn't call id, i call entityId..  I try to semplificate...

Comment: @Fogmeister output if you do NSLog(@"%@", json); is { "id": "2559", "tags": [ {Tag1}, {Tag2} ] }

Comment: @HotLicks in log (in debug) i see that myentity.tags is NSArray with size 2 and whem I open [] []

Comment: @Alessandro is that the actual format of the input json at the beginning of your question?

Comment: That's invalid JSON (and is not what you listed earlier).

Comment: @Alessandro if that's the output then those Tag1 and Tag2 objects are very odd. They're not NSStrings. I'm not sure what they are. Can you do this... `NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` and then `NSLog(@"%@", myString);` and tell me the output of that.

Comment: @HotLicks that output isn't the json data it's the NSDictionary object created by the json-object conversion.

Comment: List *precisely* what you get when you **NSLog** myEntity.tags.

Comment: Please use copy/paste to show us precisely what NSLog is showing as the values of the various values.  So far you've been bungling them pretty badly.

Comment: "that output isn't the json data it's the NSDictionary object created by the json-object conversion" -- BS -- NSLog would not present an NSDictionary in that fashion.

Answer (score 5):

This is too long for a comment but it's turning into a dragging conversation of comments.

Copy and Paste the exact code you use otherwise we can't help you.

If I use the JSON you have given then it all works fine

```
NSString *JSONString =
@"{"
  @"\"id\": \"2559\","
  @"\"tags\": ["
    @"\"Tag1\","
    @"\"Tag2\""
  @"]"
@"}";

NSData *JSONData = [JSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData
                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                       error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", [json objectForKey:@"tags"]);
//=> 2013-02-12 16:52:24.076 Test[52992:c07] (
//     Tag1,
//     Tag2
//   )
```

I'll delete this answer once the endless comment thread from lack of clarity has finished